# Web API Filter sending error response immediately

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, filter

What is the standard way to gracefully exit a web api filter?

I seem to have the following two options within a web api filter:

> 1. throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
> 2. filterContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

Option one exits the filter immediately but I have to throw an exception.

Option two seems more graceful but code will continue in the filter so i have to if else the crap out of my filter.

What is the standard way to do this? My googling hasn't resulted in a clear path forward. Is there some third unicorn way to do this that is more magical?

Comment: What is the filter doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have my answer after talking to a co-worker. Tell me if my approach is wrong.

It seems it will just be better to restructure my filter. I will put my filter code in a function that returns a bool. In my function i can just return at any time. Then my filter will just check the bool response and return authorized or unauthorized

Comment: It depends on what your filter is doing. Based on your question it seems like you're talking about an authorization filter. If your code is in the overridden method for determining if the user is authorized (which returns a Boolean) you're correct that returning "false" will do exactly what you're looking for

Comment: Yeah i wrote a custom auth filter because the standard approach didn't quite fit my needs. Everything seems good now. I put the perm checks in a separate function and return a bool to my OnAuthorization method. No expensive exceptions and it returns right away.